# Using "Any" within "Any" on an Entity Framework Core IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am currently attempting to write a query using Entity Framework Core 2.1 that will include an `.Any()` clause within an `.Any()` clause. However the debug statements are indicating to me that:

> 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

I can't use contains as the values I want are a property on the model themselves but I also don't want to fire off multiple subqueries and would prefer this into one SQL statement.

The query portion of note is:

```
query = query.Where(p => p.Lots
                          .Any(lt => queryParameters.ActivityStatus
                                                    .Any(st => st == lt.ActivityStatus)));
```

where `p.Lots =>` is a collection of model objects, and `queryParameters.ActgivityStatus =>` is a list of supplied statuses I want to check that they exist

Comment: *"I can't use contains as the values I want are a property on the model themselves"* Not really. `.Any(st => st == lt.ActivityStatus)` is the same as `.Contains(lt.ActivityStatus)`

Comment: Really cause I read that they were subtle different in EF??? But ok lets say you are right ..  My original query still stands in that how can I get EF to translate the expression to a SQL query and not evaluate in memory ..?

Comment: And `Contains` construct translates, isn't it?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm sorry I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains instead of any.

```
query = query.Where(p => p.Lots
             .Any(lt =>
                 queryParameters.ActivityStatus
                    .Contains(lt.ActivityStatus)
             )
        );
```